# State Diagram Issue - Equivalent Situations

Tags: state-machines

How do I know according to the following diagram if I have a equivalent situations, how do I recognize it?
[image: State Diagram]

for example we will examine S2 and S3.

I would like to get an advice how to do it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if there are states where:

1. Outputs are the same for all possible inputs, and that
2. "Next states" are also the same for the same input combinations (except where the next state is just jumping from one equivalent state to the other, which is the same as no state change at all).

Answer (score 2):

If two different states goes to the same state with the same output when the same input comes, they are the same state :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to perform state minimization is via the [Partitioning Method](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp08/cse140/lectures/wk6.pdf). Basically, you need to set up your state diagram in a state table. From there, you are looking at which inputs have the same outputs, and finally, which states lead to the same next state. The information on partitioning begins on page 6 of those slides.